# .htaccess redirect from http to https not working for chrome

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, redirect, https

I have added a .htaccess file with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^arrakis-systems\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.arrakis-systems.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My intention is to redirect ONLY the main page from http to https. Did I do that correctly, or would you recommend doing this differently?

I tested this on Firefox and Edge and both seem to work fine. But when I test it on Chrome, and clear my cache, it seems to not redirect, but rather stay on the http page. Thanks for your help!

Comment: "My intention is to redirect ONLY the main page" - Why? Why not every page (which is what this rule does)? Why are you checking the requested `Host` header? This is a server-side redirect, so there would be no difference between browsers, except for caching. Are you sure you are not requesting the www subdomain on Chrome? (You are specifically excluding the www subdomain from the redirect for some reason.)

Comment: FWIW I just tested your site on Chrome and the redirect "works" as expected.

Comment: We have some http items that still need to be reached, and isn't a fan of the https redirect. Thank you for checking! I have no clue why my Chrome isn't working. 

I am checking the Host header to make sure that it only affects the main page. Or at least that is what I assume I am doing. (Novice here) Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do I add a Rewrite condition specifically for a www.arrakis-systems.com as well? Or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Do you have multiple domains point to this one hosting account?

Comment: I have a arrakissystems.com forwarding to arrrakis-systems.com. Is that what you mean?